# Final step in proving $(C[0, 1], \|\cdot\|_1)$ is not a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, complete-spaces

**My professor did the following proof in my functional analysis lecture:
Check that $(C[0, 1], \|\cdot\|_1)$ is not a Banach space, where $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,{\rm d}x.$**

**Proof:** taking  $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ a sequence in $C[0, 1]$ given by: $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt x}, &\text{ if }  \frac{1}{n} \le x  \le 1 \\ \sqrt n, &\text{ if } 0 \le x  \le \frac{1}{n} \end{cases} $$

If $n > m$, I computed: $$\|f_m - f_n\|_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt m} - \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

Sending $m,n$ to $+\infty $ , $$\|f_m - f_n\|_1 \rightarrow 0$$ which proves that the sequence is Cauchy

Then if $\exists f \in C[0, 1]$ such that when  $ n\rightarrow \infty , \|f_n - f\|_1\rightarrow 0 $
now when $ k\rightarrow \infty , f_{n_k} \rightarrow  f  $ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$, then $f(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty } f_{n_k}(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$

but no continuous function $f$ in $[0,1]$  exists that coincides almost everywhere with the function  $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, x \in [0,1]$ , therefore  $C[0, 1]$ is not complete

**I don't understand the part after Cauchyness of $(f_n)$ is proven**
Where did that $k$ variable come from? Looks like it has to do with a subsequence but I don't get what they are doing and where did that "almost everywhere" come from too ? How did they get the function out of the 1-norm?  From this, how does it follow $\lim_{k \to \infty } f_{n_k}(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$ ?
And then he writes "but no continuous function $f$ in $[0,1]$  exists that coincides almost everywhere with the function  $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, x \in [0,1]$", how can you know that if that is precisely what we are trying to prove here ?
Can someone help me clear this up?

Note: I am just starting with measure theory, so I know "almost everywhere" means "except in a zero-measure set", but I have no experience, so please be explicit if using some known property or theorem

Thanks.

Comment: Recall tah convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence almost everywhere of a subsequence.

Comment: @Tito Eliatron I'm sorry I am not familiar with that, I still can't make the connection with measure theory, why is that?

Comment: Look [T.Tao Modes of Convergece](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/), Corollary 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm that is used is the $L^1([0,1])$ norm.

It is known in measure theory, that if a sequence of functions converges in $L^1([0,1])$,
that there exists a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere to the same limit.
This subsequence is most likely where the $k$ comes from.

The convergence $\lim_k f_{n_k}(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{x}}$
can be concluded from the pointwise convergence
$\lim_n f_n(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ for all $x\in (0,1]$.

No continuous function from $C[0,1]$ exists which coincides with $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$
almost everywhere because
all functions from $C[0,1]$ are bounded.
But if a function is equal to $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ almost everywhere,
then it cannot be bounded by some $M>1$, because $f(x)>M$ holds for $x\in (0,1/M^2)$,
and the set $(0,1/M^2)$ has positive measure.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this "well known resoult" is, in fact, due to F. Riesz, Sur les suites de fonctions mesurables, Paris Acad. Sci. C.R. 148 (1909), 1303--1305.

Comment: what about the statement "no continuous function $f$ in $[0,1]$  exists that coincides almost everywhere with the function  $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, x \in [0,1]$", where does that come from?

Comment: of course $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, x \in [0,1]$ is not defined in x=0

Comment: @mathlover If there exists such a function, say $g$, as $g(0)$ exists and is finite, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(0)|<1$ for $|x|<delta$. So $|g(x)<|g(0)|+1$ "near" $x=0$ but $1/\sqrt x$ explodes at $x=0$. Can you imagine the rest?

Comment: uhm, I thought the problem was only on$ x=0$ and that by taking out the set $\{0\}$ which is just one point and therefore has zero measure , there was coincidence almost everywhere

Comment: @supinf Perhaps you meant  "if a sequence of functions converges", instead of " if a function converges"